# Shader nodes 3rd side of the polygon

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to get a smooth gradient on all 3 edges of every polygon, but I've been struggling how to address the 3rd one for some time now. Do you have any idea what node setup can achieve it?
Or maybe someone have an idea how to smooth the output of the wireframe node?
[image]

Comment: Math -> Absolute value can possibly sort this out

Comment: I tried implementing the math absolute node but with no success so far :/